# How to install TexMaker on Mac?

Tags: macos, install, latex

I want to install TexMaker 4.5 on Mac OS X 10.9.5. On [the official page](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html), I clicked on `Texmaker 4.5 for MacosxLion (64 bits)` and opened the folder that is downloaded. It contains the application `texmaker`.

I double-clicked it and made a small MWE. If I want to compile it, it says

```
Could not start the command.
"pdflatex" -syntex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

What should I do? Do I have to install LaTeX separately befor installing a compiler?

**Update**

I have installed LaTeX separately according to Monomeeth's answer below. Apparently, TexMaker 4.5 did not find them or it was not the correct version.

Next, I installed a version of MacTex manually according to [this site](http://tug.org/mactex/faq/3-4.html), namely the 2016 version. Now TexMaker 4.5 is able to compile a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Texmaker is only an editor, you need to install TeX/LaTex separately and configure Texmaker to find the correct binaries. From [Configuring the latex related commands](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION02):

> Texmaker can't compile yours documents if the paths to the LaTeX related commands are wrong.
>   The default settings should work with the recent and standard LaTeX distributions, but you should have to modify them ("Configure Texmaker" -> "Commands").

There are several TeX/LaTeX packages for macOS out there, I'm using [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) for several years now.

Comment: FWIW, You can install it with Homebrew-Cask:
  `brew cask install mactex`

Answer (score 4):

It's not 100% clear to me what you've actually tried, but give this a go:

1. Launch Terminal
2. Enter the following command:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask 2> /dev/null`

3. Press enter and wait while the command runs
4. When it's complete, enter: `brew cask install texmaker`

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Completed the 4 points successfully. When I open a `.tex` file, texmaker crashes. In the crash log, I see that TexMaker 5.0.1 was installed, but I need version 4.5 for Mac OS X 10.9.5. So I installed TexMaker 4.5 manually as mantioned in the OP.